# Multiple conditions from single column in dataframe, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select a subset from a single dataframe column, and I need help applying two conditions on a single column. For example, how do I select for both "Tom" and "Chris" in the table below?

```
import pandas as pd
dic={"Name":["Chris","Tom","Steven"], "Age":[12,34,55]}
dic={"Name":["Chris","Tom","Steven"], "Age":[12,34,55]}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
df[df["Name"]=="Tom"]
```

Why is it that when I use
      `df[df["Name"]==("Chris" or "Tom")]`
it picks "Chris, but when or is replaced by and, "Tom" is selected?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the order of operations. The first thing that happens is `"Chris" or "Tom"` which is a pretty bizarre operation. Python has 'truthiness' for strings. Any non-empty string evaluates as `True`. Follow MaxU's explanation for the rest.

Answer (score 5):

when we check `condition1 OR condition2` - it's enough if first condition/operand is `True`, so if the first one is True - the second will **not** be checked (because it's enough to have one `True`):

```
In [247]: 1 or 2
Out[247]: 1
```

for AND we must check also the second one if the first one is `True` (because **all** conditions must be `True`):

```
In [248]: 1 and 2
Out[248]: 2
```

but if the first condition is `False` we don't need to check the second one (because it's enough to have one `False` - it'll make the whole "thing" `False`):

```
In [250]: 0 and 1
Out[250]: 0
```

The same logic will be applied to strings (NOTE: empty strings will be evaluated as `False`):

```
In [242]: ("Chris" or "Tom")
Out[242]: 'Chris'

In [249]: ("Chris" and "Tom")
Out[249]: 'Tom'
```

so when you do

```
df[df["Name"]==("Chris" or "Tom")]
```

it's the same as:

```
df[df["Name"]=="Chris"]
```

**how to do it properly (in a Pandas way)** :

```
In [243]: df[df["Name"].isin(["Chris","Tom"])]
Out[243]:
   Age   Name
0   12  Chris
1   34    Tom
```